# can't call/send sms between 2 android emulators

Tags: android, phone-call

Even after starting up 2 emulators when I dial to call the other emulator it disconnects automatically after pressing the dial button its all the same case for sending an sms can't send message from one emulator to another

Comment: first search your question here. if it is not then ask question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call or SMS from one emulator to another directly. Instead, you can simulate the aforementioned, as shown step by step in the following links:

http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/simulating-sms-in-android-emulator-t1396.html
[http://www.slegg.net/simulate-incoming-call-with-android-emulator/](http://www.slegg.net/simulate-incoming-call-with-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call between emulators you just need to use the console port number of the emulator you want to call to into the dialer of the emulator you want to call from. This is displayed as a number in the title of the emulator window, e.g. `5554:my_emulator_name`. In this case you would call to 5554.